# ng e2e is failing, for chrome driver download location becomes unreachable

Tags: node.js, angular, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

[image: error for the command ng e2e]

from yesterday, all of a sudden ng e2e is failing during chromedriver setup step... not having a clue.

OS - Ubuntu 18.04

Node - 13.12.0 [also tested in 12.0.0, same error]

Angular CLI - 8.3.25

Comment: Was there an update to the browser? what's the current browser version on the machine?

Comment: chrome Version 80.0.3987.149 , it was released in a week, but more importantly I cant access https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/ from any of my browsers, one of my colleague in my country cant access it also. so going to try vpn ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem, for e2e running with angular cli. Follow the steps below, anyone facing same problem. In my country, the download URL for chrome driver became unreachable.

0) use a VPN for downloading the chromedriver, a specific one you need. the idea is not checking for update every test run. I used protonvpn's free service.

1) install protractor globally

`npm install protractor -g`

update webdriver manager with specific version of chrome driver

`webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=80.0.3987.163`

2) locate the selenium folder in the global installation, for me its
`/home/adnan/.nvm/versions/node/v12.0.0/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium`

3)
 copy the contents to a folder, 'selenium-backup' inside your e2e folder

4) update protractor.conf.js, with something like this, a relative location respect to your `protractor.conf.js`

`exports.config = {
     ....
     chromeDriver: './e2e/selenium-backup/chromedriver_80.0.3987.163',
     ....
    }`

ref: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

5) have a script defined in your angular application's package.json

`"e2e-xu": "ng e2e --webdriverUpdate=false"`

6) to run the e2e, use this command
    `npm run e2e-xu`

7) make sure your CI environment download chrome of `version 80.0.3987.163` , rather than latest stable